# Скрипт появления блока DIV при прокрутки страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите разобраться. При загрузке страницы, если не трогать скролл, элемент #back-top первоначально отображается на экране. После при прокрутке страницы начинает работать как положено. В css стоит display:none;, но первоначально не реагирует на него.

```js
jQuery(function(f){
    var element = f('#back-top');
    f(window).scroll(function(){
        element['fade'+ (f(this).scrollTop() > 200 ? 'In': 'Out')](500);           
    });
});
```

```css
#back-top {
 position: fixed;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 display: none;
}
#back-top img {
 opacity: 0.3;cursor: pointer;
}
#back-top img:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="back-top" style="display: block;"><img src="http://vanna.br31.ru/img/master_zamera.png" alt="вызвать мастера" /></div>
```

Comment: В мобильном Хроме, и после прокрутки работает криво: элемент не всегда появляется (это как-то зависит от "характера" свайпа).

Answer (score 1):

Инлайн-стиль `style="display: block;"` уберите... Такие стили имеют приоритет над стилями содержащимися в тегах `<style>` и в CSS-файлах.

*p.s.: И элементам `div` бессмысленно задавать `display: block`, когда нет перекрытия (потому что в HTML, для этих элементов значение `block` - изначальное).*

---

```js
jQuery(function(f){
    var element = f('#back-top');
    f(window).scroll(function(){
        element['fade'+ (f(this).scrollTop() > 200 ? 'In': 'Out')](500);           
    });
});
```

```css
#back-top {
 position: fixed;
 right: 0px; bottom: 0px;
 display: none;
}
#back-top img { opacity: 0.3;cursor: pointer; }
#back-top img:hover { opacity: 1; }

#empty-space {
  height: 700px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff 199px, #d447 199px, #d447 201px, #fff 201px); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="empty-space">
<div id="back-top">
  <img src="http://vanna.br31.ru/img/master_zamera.png" alt="вызвать мастера">
</div>
```